Counting scenes in a screenplay
I'm starting to break down and shot list my script and I am wondering how I would count the scenes in this sequence:
EXT. THE PARK - DAY

(stuff happens)

INT. LYRA'S BEDROOM - DAY

(stuff happens)

EXT. THE PARK - DAY

(direct continuation from previous scene at the park)

For the purpose of script breakdown, naming shots (e.g., 1A, 4E), et cetera, should I count this sequence as three scenes or are the scenes at the park considered the same scene?

Whenever your narrative switches to a different time or location or character from the present one, there is a scene break and a new scene begins. It doesn't matter if a later scene is a continuation of an earlier one. As long as there is a change in time or location or character between two adjacent scenes, it is a new scene.
